# Summing 2 or more specific values from a table with multiple values inside it column

Tags: sqlite

I have a table called products with the columns: Product, Price, Size and Units.

It has a total of 10 products in it but some products are repeated twice but have a different value for Price and/or Size.

Id like to use a command to see how much was spent on just Soup and Dogfood. If it matters, there are 2 occurrences of Dogfood in the Products; one with a price of 700, the other of 200 and just one of Soup which has a price of 257.

I know how to sum all the prices up in my table:

SELECT SUM (Price)
...> from products;

but I cant think of a way to exclude certain ones and add the remaining.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Id like the sum of the cost of one soup and the 2 dogfoods that are in the table

Comment: Stack Overflow's question/answer format is not suitable to learn all the basics. You should work through some [SQL tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, rows can be filtered with the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT SUM(Price)
FROM Products
WHERE Product = 'Soup'
   OR Product = 'Dogfood';
```